# nginx SSL termination with sticky load balancing

Tags: nginx, sticky-sessions, websocket

I want to use Nginx with a socket.io app with TLS/SSL termination at the load balancer. Is it possible to use the `ip_hash` directive to do sticky loadbalancing in combination with TLS/SSL termination? My application only uses HTTPS.

I could not find any resource except [this article](https://www.nginx.com/blog/choosing-nginx-plus-load-balancing-techniques/#ip-hash) which says sticky loadbalancing isn't applicable with TLS/SSL and I'm confused!

article quote:

> IP Hash (available for HTTP only) is a predefined variant of the Hash method, in which the hash is based on the client’s IP address. You set it with the ip_hash directive.

Comment: Where does it says that? HTTP there means that it's not available for stream module

Comment: The `ip_hash` is solely used to make the requests "stick" agains the upstream server. Are you using nginx as the load balancer in front of other socket.io app servers?

Comment: @MikeFiedler
Yes,As a loadbalancer and ssl terminator!

Comment: @AlexeyTen
this part:

`IP Hash (available for HTTP only) is a predefined variant of the Hash method, in which the hash is based on the client’s IP address. You set it with the ip_hash directive.`

Comment: You could just try and see result. It'll take 10 minutes